# How to define const variable on RAM?

Tags: c, embedded, microcontroller, powerpc

I am using MPC5644A freescale EVB board.

I need to find a way to define const variable in ram. So On LCF file I pointed these variable on RAM location of mpc5644. But in run time i am taking IVOR1 as I expected.

There is one main rule. I can not change const variable's type or name. But I need to use these variables in RAM with determined area like "calibration_ram"

Any help can be so good.

**My C Source is like below:**

```
#pragma push /* Save the current state */
#pragma section sconst_type ".__cal_DataArea"

volatile const real32_T freq2rpm;
volatile const real32_T high_voltage;
#pragma pop
```

...

**MY LCF File:**

```
MEMORY
{

calibration_ram :      org = 0x40040000,   len = 0x00010000

...


SECTIONS
{

    .__bam_bootarea LOAD (ADDR(resetvector)): {} > resetvector
    .__cal_DataArea LOAD (ADDR(calibration_ram)): {} > calibration_ram

...
```

Comment: I don't really understand your question.  You want a `const` in RAM?  compile it in.   You want it at a specific location?   You seem to have accomplished that(or are on your way.   linker descriptor files are very tool chain specific so I can't tell if you're doing it right for whatever unnamed toolset you're using).  If you want something different, please explain what you want to accomplish.

Comment: You are using the Codewarrior compiler, correct? And indeed, this question doesn't make any sense on a flash-based microcontroller. If you want a constant, put it in flash. If you want a non-constant, but it in RAM, period.

Comment: Anyways, I'm far from a linker script wizard, but try this: `#pragma section sconst_type ".__cal_DataArea" ".__cal_DataArea"
__declspec(section ".calibration_ram") `. LCF file looks ok as far as I can tell.

Comment: Location is determined by the linker than the than the compiler and as such linker directives in the source code are not part of the standard language syntax but are tool-chain specific.  You therefore need to specify what tool-chain you are using in the question and tags so on one has to guess.  Critically perhaps if the `#pragma` directives you have used are not recognised by your compiler, they will be ignored, possibly without warning.

Comment: @Lundin: On faster MCUs like ARM Cortex-M3/4 Flash often adds lots of waitstates. Even more if you prefetch instructions at the same time. So for speed-critical code, it might really become an issue.

Comment: @Olaf Whether to put a variable in ROM or not is a conceptual program design issue, it has nothing to do with performance. If you need to copy-down constants from flash to RAM, then they need to be non-constant. (Though MPC56 adds 2 wait states if clocked past 60MHz and 3 wait states if clocked past 80MHz. It has pre-fetch buffers though, so unless you are reading lots of data from flash, there shouldn't be any performance issues.)

Comment: @Lundin: OP asks about `const` variables, not constants. That is a fundamental difference, as the first is only a contract. 2) This might be of intrest for other architectures, too (that's why I mentioned the C-M3/4). 3) it often is not so much a matter of how many accesses but frequency. An high-frequency interrupt (consider a high-speed PID with coefficient-table) may possibly have both. That is one of the target-appications of the MPC56. 5) Not sure about the MPC56, but often Flash prefetch-buffers are either for code-only, or interfere with code-prefetch and/or have other penalties.

Comment: @Olaf I know the difference, creating a `const` contract for RAM variables is trivial, use your usual, everyday private encapsulation techniques. If you need something in RAM for whatever reason, write some copy-down code that copies it from flash into `static` read/write buffers, then only access those buffers through a const pointer, which is obtained from a "getter" function. You need no linker script magic to make that: just use plain standard C.

Comment: @Lundin: That might be the answer OP is looking for. (Although it might be useful on some architectures like DSP, but also e.g. Cortex-M7 with instruction-TCM to have support from the linker & startup so you can still use modular programming.)

Answer (score 0):

When i try with below line, it is solved. I can define const variable on RAM

```
#pragma explicit_zero_data on
#pragma push
#pragma section sconst_type const_type   ".__cal_DataArea" ".__cal_DataArea"
...
..
```

Thanks All.